# Dispose, Finalize, SuppressFinalize methods

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Can i implement this two methods in the same class?

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  // some implementation
  // if i missed to call Dispose() method;
  ~MyClass()
  {
  // it means, clear all does not mananage resources 
  // but dont use Dispose() method 
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
   // clear resources
   // if i call this method will i can do this:
   GC.SuppressFinalize()
   // it means dont use Finalizw method for this object
  }
}
```

Am i right? Because i cant understand this  GC.SuppressFinalize() method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can implement both methods as you see.

Generally, the correct pattern if an object can have both managed and unmanaged references is:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  ~MyClass()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
    Dispose(true);
  }
  public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if(disposing)
    {
      // clear MANAGED references
    }
    // free UNMANAGED resources
  }
}
```

But you can implement this as you want. This is just a pattern. For example, if you don't have any unmanaged resources and your class is sealed (so you can be sure it won't use any unmanaged resources, ever), you could implement it just like:

```
public sealed class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
    // release managed references
  }
}
```

And forget about finalizers.

In the first pattern, what `GC.SuppresFinalize(this)` is doing, is telling the garbage collector that it should not call the finalizer (the `~MyClass()` method) upon freeing the object: if you have specifically called `Dispose()` then you have **already** called your virtual  `Dispose(bool)` function, so why call it again?

The problem is that the finalizer by itself in C# is non-deterministic: you don't know when it will be called... you don't even have the guarantee that it'll even be called (although it will during normal cleanup if it was not called before), that's why `IDisposable` exists, it's a way of *deterministically* release the managed references held up your objects, and free and release the unmanaged resources allocated by it.

If an object is being freed up by the GC, all managed references that it holds will be released too, so there's no need to clear *managed* references when a finalizer is called.

However your application should do a best effort to free and release any unmanaged resources it has.

If you forgot to `Dispose()`, there should be a last chance for them to get freed (when the GC collects the object, or upon the final cleanup when the application runs). That's wehy in the normal pattern you also implement a finalizer, and tell it to clean up unmanaged resources *if you have not done it before*

Take note that, contrary to popular belief, a call to `Dispose()` is nothing special, it's just a method call: you could call it `FreeMyObject()` or `FooBar()` if you wanted. It does NOT make the garbage collector free up any memory. There's a *pattern* by using `IDisposable`, so important that it gets its own language syntax construct (the `using` block), but it's just that, a pattern. You could do the same thing that `Dispose()` does without implementing `IDisposable` at all.

Comment: Why method public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) is marked as virtual? Does that mean that in child classes we can override it, forgeting to free some memory of base class, and create memory leak?

Comment: @MishaHuziuk the idea is that derived classes should override the method, clean up their own resources (the ones they added on the derived class) and call `base.Dispose()` afterwards. Of course noone prevents you from not calling the base method and creating a leak, but then again, nothing prevents you from calling `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`, or `Thread.Abort()` or anything else on your class that may create problems.

Comment: Got it. Thank's!